# aspx.net login page with rds database via Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, asp.net, amazon-rds

I have developed a login page and connected to my aws rds database via mysql workbench. I have created tables and can insert new registration of user. but for the login.aspx, I am writing the same codes for login.aspx.cs like local database connection but mine doesn't seem working and it is not taking me to home page when I click login button. Can anyone help me find what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!
here's my login.aspx;

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="loginfinal.aspx.cs" Inherits="Aname.login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <asp:Image runat="server" imageURL="~/images/PlantManager.jfif" width="200px"/>
            <asp:Image ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" imageURL="~/images/quote.jfif" height="128px" />
            <asp:Image runat="server" imageURL="~/images/TeamLogo.jfif" width="126px"/>


            <div style="text-align:right">
               <asp:Hyperlink ID="Hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="AboutUsPM.aspx" runat="server">About Plant Manager </asp:Hyperlink>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">


            <asp:label runat="server"> <b> UserID </b> </asp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:TextBox id="Txtid" CssClass="auto-style2" placeholder="Enter UserID" runat="server" Height="42px" Width="55%"/></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txtid" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="You cannot leave this blank." ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">

            <asp:label runat="server"> <b> Password </b> </asp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">
            <asp:TextBox id="TxtPsw" CssClass="auto-style5" Textmode="Password" placeholder="Enter Password" runat="server" Height="42px" Width="55%"/></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtPsw" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="You cannot leave this blank." ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">

            <asp:Checkbox ID="Chkrmb" CssClass="checkbox-inline" Text="Remember me" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">

                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">

            <asp:Hyperlink ID="MyHyperLinkControl" NavigateUrl="~/forgetpsw.aspx" runat="server">Forget password? </asp:Hyperlink>

                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="auto-style4">

            <asp:Button ID="Btnlogin" CssClass="auto-style6" Text="Login" OnClick="Btnlogin_Click" style="color:white" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration='none'" runat="server" />


                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                </table>


            &nbsp;</div>

</form>
```

login.aspx.cs file:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Aname
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
//rds connection string
        static string connection = @"Server=rds-mysql.xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com; Port=xxxx; Database=mydb; User Id=xxxx; password=xxxxx";
    MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(connection);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData("");

        }
    }

    private void LoadData(string text)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlConnection sqlquery = new MySqlConnection(connection))
        {
            string query = "SELECT user_id, name, contact_no, email, role FROM mydb.User ; ";
            MySqlDataAdapter adpter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, sqlquery);
            adpter.Fill(dt);
        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["user_id"] = Txtid.Text;
            Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx");
        }
    }
    protected void Btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        string query = "select count(*) from mydb.User where user_id='" + Txtid.Text + "'and pass='" + TxtPsw.Text + "'";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
        int output = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        sqlcon.Close();

        if (output == 1)
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from mydb.User where user_id='" + Txtid.Text + "'";
            MySqlCommand checkpsw = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
            string password = checkpsw.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            if (password == TxtPsw.Text)
            {
                Session["user_id"] = Txtid.Text;
                Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Password is incorrect!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("UserID is incorrect!");
        }

     }

}
}
```

Comment: "not working" means what? What error do you get? Is your database server set up to allow connections from wherever your application is hosted?

Comment: The page can view in browser and no error detected when debugging. what i mean for "not working" is that the page doesn't redirect me to my home page that I put as response.redirect. Yes. I have allowed the connections in my database and it works well in my register page.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure, that the output  is 1? And are you absolutely sure you are typing correct password ? Put a response or console.write to a few places for debugging purposes.

Comment: If there's no exception, then it's more likely simply the data in your new database is not what you're expecting. BTW your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, you should use parameterised queries to stop malicious input from stealing or corrupting your data.

Comment: @Niko The password and connection part is absolutely correct but I am not so sure about the output I put. Yes, I debugged at Page load point and I found out my errors. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the sugguestion!! I really didn't notice about all those security parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my updated login.aspx.cs codes if anyone wants to know;

```
     public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static string connection = @"Server=rds-mysql.xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com; Port=xxxx; Database=mydb; User Id=xxxx; password=xxxxx";
    MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(connection);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadData("");
        }
    }

    private void LoadData(string text)
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        string query = "select * from mydb.User where user_id='" + Txtid.Text + "'";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
        try
        {
            string output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from mydb.User where password='" + TxtPsw.Text + "'";

            MySqlCommand checkpsw = new MySqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, sqlcon);
            string password = null;
            try
            {
                password = checkpsw.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                Session["user_id"] = Txtid.Text;
                Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Ltlup.Text = "UserID or password is incorrect!";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Ltlup.Text = "UserID or password is incorrect!";
        }
```